# Why does the proof of $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$ work from the case solution?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

There is certain proof:

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$ *where $x, y, \geq 0$*

And by doing some rough work (starting with the above equation to see if the proof is true), it ends up to be of the case (i.e. case 1) $x \geq y$:

$\sqrt{xy} \geq y$

However, the question solution states that this is true because:

$\sqrt{xy} > \sqrt{y\cdot y} = y$

I do not seem to get this. An explanation and/or next steps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying $x \geq y$ with $y$ we get $xy \geq yy = y^2$, because these are positive numbers. Since the square root is a strictly increasing function, it preserves orders and thus $\sqrt{xy}\geq \sqrt{y^2}=y$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I just need to clarify what you meant by "the square is a strictly increasing function, it preserves orders", why you need to mention that to square root both sides? Thanks

Comment: It just means that for positive numbers $a, b$ for which $a\leq b$, it follows that $\sqrt{a}\leq \sqrt{b}$. If one regards the square root as a real function, one can show that this order preserving follows from the fact that it is a strictly increasing function. Does this clarify things for you?

Comment: Sure, sort of. What do you mean by "order preserving"? Thanks.

Comment: An operation is order preserving if it preserves order. Here, we say that the square root preserves the order (the inequality): "if $a\leq b$, then also $\sqrt{a}\leq \sqrt{b}$".

Comment: Okay, thank you.